# SQL ORDER BY expression with multiple conditions

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

Here's the code snippet used to perform the ordering

```
ORDER BY
  case when (app.pricing 
             AND app.enforce_reporting
             AND (uas.count IS NULL OR uas.count_reported_at IS NULL)
            ) then 1 end DESC,  
  LEFT(sst.name, 3) DESC, 
  uas.updated_at DESC;
```

columns `app.pricing` `app.enforce_reporting` have boolean values

However, the query seems to ignore the first ORDER BY case and only orders the result with `LEFT(sst.name, 3) DESC` and `uas.updated_at DESC`.

What could be missing here?

SampleData:

```
#<AppPricingPlan id: "b2de59bd03da4c8cb130cd434ce6e1d1", application_id: "f34cdb27341a4e7498604172b677bc38", pricing: true, plan_name: "$2 pricing", enforce_reporting: true>
#<AppPricingPlan id: "2dde59bd03da4c8cb130cd434ce6e1d1", application_id: "f345db27341a4e7498604172b677bc38", pricing: false, plan_name: "$4 pricing", enforce_reporting: false>
#<AppPricingPlan id: "85e4505eea5440fca1d492e96c5f513b", application_id: "d745db27341a4e7498604172b677bc38", pricing: true, plan_name: "$4 pricing", enforce_reporting: true>

#<UserAppSale id: "7e18a8f2c7164042badc35b6835139ef", user_id: "e376d378869e45bc96cf3061a45aj664", application_id: "1c4d242e38e9463d835e27322e6f353c", app_pricing_plan_id: "2b6e59bd03da4c8cb130cd434ce6e1d1", active: true, created_at: "2023-03-16 15:23:34", updated_at: "2023-03-17 12:32:07", count: 22, count_reported_at: "2023-03-17 12:32:07">
#<UserAppSale id: "9e18a8f2c7164042badc35b6835139ef", user_id: "e906d378869e45bc96cf3061a45aj664", application_id: "1c4d242e38e9463d835e27322e6f353c", app_pricing_plan_id: "85e4505eea5440fca1d492e96c5f513b", active: true, created_at: "2022-03-06 15:23:34", updated_at: "2022-03-17 12:32:07", count: 0, count_reported_at: nil>
#<UserAppSale id: "2f18a8f2c7164042badc35b6835139ef", user_id: "e906d378869e45bc96cf3061a45aj664", application_id: "1c4d242e38e9463d835e27322e6f353c", app_pricing_plan_id: "b2de59bd03da4c8cb130cd434ce6e1d1", active: true, created_at: "2023-03-11 05:23:34", updated_at: "2022-03-14 12:32:07", count: 0, count_reported_at: nil>
```

Expected Result(in order of):

```
#<UserAppSale id: "9e18a8f2c7164042badc35b6835139ef"...>
#<UserAppSale id: "2f18a8f2c7164042badc35b6835139ef"...>
#<UserAppSale id: "7e18a8f2c7164042badc35b6835139ef"...>
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @TheImpaler updated with more info, thanks.

Comment: It is not obvious how the two tables are related. If the first `ORDER BY` column makes no difference, that indicates that the first column is identical for all rows.

Comment: @muskrat, you asked, "What could be missing here?" The short answer: the `JOIN`s and `WHERE` conditions. Without those, it's impossible to provide a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

You case condition specifies what to do when the combination of predicates returns TRUE. However, it does NOT specify what to do when that combination returns FALSE (or null), so a not true result returns NULL. The `order by`  clause defaults to `nulls last` without regard the any ACS/DESC. The `order by` is not ignoring the first criteria just following the default as you did not specify otherwise. So

```
order by
  case when (app.pricing 
             and app.enforce_reporting
             and (uas.count is null or uas.count_reported_at is null)
            ) then 1 end NULLS FIRST   -->>> instead of desc  
  left(sst.name, 3) desc, 
  uas.updated_at desc;
```

At least that seems to be what you want although even that is obscure. If not update your question to contain the complete query and table definitions (ddl). Also reformat your test data into columnar form: example (see [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/))

```
+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
|        "AppPricingPlan id"        |          application_id          | pricing |  plan_name   | enforce_reporting    |
+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
|  b2de59bd03da4c8cb130cd434ce6e1d1 | f34cdb27341a4e7498604172b677bc38 | true    | "$2 pricing" | true                 |
+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+
```

or better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and actually populate tables with the test data.